# Change SMS authentication text display

Tags: sms, customization, docusignapi, customizing

After integrating with the docusign API with SMS authentication, we saw that the default text entered for the subscriber when clicking on the signature link was not ideal. Can we change this text (that initial message asking the user to select a phone and click send SMS)? We were able to change the body of the email sent, but this text could not. I looked in the documentation and could not find, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize SMS Auth screen by modifying signing resource file in your Branding in DocuSign Connect.[Signing Resource Doc](https://docs.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/DocuSign-Signing-Resource-File(v2.0).pdf) explains how to do it, please check `Pages # 18, 19 and 20`.